# How do I run rails g model / rake db:migrate within my rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to run "rails g model" and / or "rake db:migrate" within my rails application.
When I do it , The "rails g model" works fine, but take long,
and "rake db:migrate" raised an error

```
SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked
```

The error occurs only when I use `after_create` and `after_save`, but works fine when I use `before_create` or `around_create`.

My model :

```
class Table < AbstractModel

     after_create :create_table

     protected

     def create_table
         system("rails g model #{self.name}")
         system("rake db:migrate")
     end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails generators are not intended to be run from within a Rails application. They're not even really necessary. They're just nice-to-haves. So instead of making a file named Table, you can run `rails g model table <attrs>` and it will generate the file table.rb in the models and generate your migration with whatever attrs you pass it.

Migrations also, should not be run within the application code. You pretty much have to manage them manually or with a deploy script.

As an aside, `after_create` is a callback for individual instances of `Table`. So when you call `Table.create({<attrs>})` it would call `create_table`, which is not what what you want.

EDIT:

Using `after_commit` not `after_create` seemed to solve the OP's problem.

Comment: Thanks, @evanbikes and @LuisMenjivar. I do want to create a table and a new model whenever I do `Table.create({<attrs>})` and I want it to be done Immediately, so my question is why `database is locked` in `after_create` callback?

Comment: Sounds like you know what you're doing. `after_create` will fire after a record is created but *before* the transaction is complete. So `after_commit :create_table, on: :create` will probably solve your locking issue.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to accomplish?. As said by evanbikes, the way you have set up is that every time you create an instance of table, you are going to generate a new model. You could run rake tasks on a schedule using cron jobs. If you are using heroku you can use heroic scheduler. Hope it helps.